# Why does read with pipeline fail in an ssh session?

Tags: ssh, pipe, quoting, read

Why does this show blank lines instead of folders found by find?

```
ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no -o userknownhostsfile=/dev/null \
  -o batchmode=yes -o passwordauthentication=no user@myserver.xx \
  "sudo find /folder/CFGKCP/KCS\ Pro/Job\ Setup -name JOBCFG.info \
    | while read linea; do echo $linea; done";
```

Comment: Try to put this you want to execute remotely in single quotes. And better create script on remote site

Comment: Why not using `xargs` instead of that while?

Comment: My workaround was use find's parameter -exec with {}, but command to execute is so complex (not the echoes in the example) that now is a mess of backslashes and quotes. For me is a mistery why a so simple thing is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Romeo pointed out, you're using double quotes around your command.  That means your variables are being expanded before doing the `ssh` command.  So the body of the while loop is

```
echo $linea
```

and before the `ssh` `linea` probably doesn't exist so the command that is passed will become just `echo` with `linea` being replaced with an empty string.

If you use single quotes around the command parameter expansion will not happen, and that string will be passed in tact through, so do

```
ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no -o userknownhostsfile=/dev/null -o batchmode=yes -o passwordauthentication=no user@myserver.xx 'sudo find /folder/CFGKCP/KCS\ Pro/Job\ Setup -name JOBCFG.info | while read linea; do echo $linea; done'
```

or escape the `$` to tell your shell not to expand it

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using double quotes. That means that `$linea` is expanded before the `ssh` is run. You can test this with `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ ssh user@host "find /var  | while read line; do echo $line; done"
+ ssh user@host 'find /var  | while read line; do echo ; done'
```

As you can see, the command actually executed is `echo` with no variable. To avoid this, you can use single quotes instead of double:

```
ssh user@host 'find /var  | while read line; do echo "$line"; done'
```

Or, run the while loop locally:

```
ssh user@host find /var  | while read line; do echo "$line"; done
```

In the example above, the `find` is run on the remote host and the `while` is run locally, on the output of the `ssh` command.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `while read` loops.

```
ssh user@mydomain.xx '
  sudo find "/folder/CFGKCP/KCS Pro/Job Setup" -name JOBCFG.info -exec sed -i "
    /^\[General]/,/^\[/ {
      s/^JobRoot = .*/JobRoot = C:\\\\LOTES\\\\TMP\\\\\r/
    }" {} +'
```

Or with single quotes:

```
ssh user@mydomain.xx '
  sudo find "/folder/CFGKCP/KCS Pro/Job Setup" -name JOBCFG.info -exec sed -i '\''
    /^\[General]/,/^\[/ {
      s/^JobRoot = .*/JobRoot = C:\\LOTES\\TMP\\\r/
    }'\'' {} +'
```

(that `\r` is already GNU-specific, so you may as well use `-i`).

Comment: @Guerraga, unless your local shell or the shell of the remote user is csh or tcsh, you don't need to put it on one line (I had a bug in that code though which should now be fixed).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the explanation about expansion of variables into quotes, now I understand where begin my problem. I still must afford with nested single quotes, because the order instead of echo uses them. This is a more detailed example:

```
ssh user@mydomain.xx '
    sudo find /folder/CFGKCP/KCS\ Pro/Job\ Setup -name JOBCFG.info|
        while read line; do
            sudo sed '/^\[General\]/,/^\[/ {s/^JobRoot = .*/JobRoot = C:\\LOTES\\TMP\\\r/}' "$line" |sudo tee "$line".modificado; sudo mv -f "$line".modificado "$line";
        done
';
```

Comment: That doesn't work because the second `'` closes the quoted string opened by the first `'`, so the `/^\General...` ends up not being quoted in the local shell (and those backslashes as then treated as quoting operators and removed there).